# If I have a gish spellcaster character, which attack would you recommend to choose from? Firebolt or Shadowblade?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, optimization

I am making a gish character, with no preference for melee or ranged attacks. However, given the two options, I think it would always be more beneficial to go range with firebolt than melee with shadowblade. What do you think?

I know that *if* you are going to be in melee, shadow-blade is better because firebolt gets disadvantage at close range, but if I have a spellcaster with high AC, and have both options to choose from, why would I choose shadow blade over firebolt? What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: Welcome to the stack Pedro, take the [tour] when you have a moment. We need to know what game you are playing, it sounds like D&D 5e, but I wanted to make sure before adding that info to the question.

Comment: Are *you* making a gish character or melee spellcaster? It seems you understand why *shadow blade* might be favorable for those characters, so I'm not sure I'm understanding your question here. I think some more details about your character and what sort of playstyle you intend to go with in combat will help us better answer your question.

Comment: Ah. I am making a gish character, with no preference for melee or ranged attacks. However, given the two options, I think it would always be more beneficial to go range with firebolt than melee with shadowblade

Comment: "Why people recommend" seems arbitrary and opinion based. Rephrasing it to ask about pros and cons of both options would make it a more answerable. And please confirm if it's D&D 5e.

Comment: Thank you, you are totally right. Just edited the question for clarity

Comment: The edited version of this question is still asking for opinions, and opinion-based questions don't work well with the voting mechanics that make the Stack Exchange work.

Answer (score 1):

### Shadowblade can use Extra Attack

If you have five levels in a martial class, you probably have the Extra Attack feature.  Extra Attack does not apply to your *firebolt* cantrip, but it does apply to weapon attacks such as *shadowblade*.

So the damage from *firebolt* is 2d10, but the damage from *shadowblade* could be 2*(2d8+4), assuming a +4 DEX.  This scales further when you cast it with higher-level spell slots.

### Shadowblade gets advantage in dim light or darkness

If your party has darkvision, it's probably not hard for you to fight in dim light or darkness a lot, so you could use this frequently.

### It's still not wonderful

This benefit comes with some drawbacks -- notably, this is a concentration spell, and if you are in melee then you're likely to get hit and lose concentration.  Also, it might take you several levels to get Extra Attack, and then more levels to get *shadowblade*, so your combo comes online later than a standard fighter's attack would.

It's true that *shadowblade* does a bunch more damage than the *firebolt* cantrip, but this isn't very exciting, because the *firebolt* cantrip does not do very much damage and is unlikely to be competitive with other characters.

If all you wanted was to deal a bunch of damage, you might consider the warlock's cantrip with *agonizing blast* and *quicken spell* instead.

Still, *shadowblade* is a thing that you can do.

Comment: We have confirmation from the asker that they're asking about 5e. No further discussion on that topic is needed.